# Error Help: There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first.

Tags: .net, sql-server, vb.net, ado.net, database-connection

I'm having this error in this part of the code and I'm still unable to figure out a solution for it

Error stats:

> ExecuteReader requires an open and available Connection. The
> connection's current state is open.

With source code in:

> Line 144:                .CommandType = CommandType.Text
>
> Line 145:     .Connection = cn
>
> Line 146:                dr = .ExecuteReader
>
> Line 147:            End With
>
> Line 148:

The code is:

```
 Public Function GetDBField(ByVal Query As String, ByVal Field As String) As String

    'abriendo la conexion a la base de datos

    SqlConnect()

    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
    Dim result As String = ""

    Dim dr As SqlDataReader
    dr = Nothing

    'ejecutando el lector de DO
    Try

        With cmd
            .CommandText = Query
            .CommandType = CommandType.Text
            .Connection = cn
            dr = .ExecuteReader
        End With



    Catch ex As SqlException
        ShowAlertMessage(ex.Message)
        GetDBField = Nothing
        Exit Function
    End Try

    'Escribiendo en una Variable de texto
    Try
        If dr.HasRows Then

        End If
        While dr.Read
            If IsDBNull(dr(Field).ToString) = True Then
                result = Nothing
            Else
                result = dr(Field).ToString
            End If
        End While
    Catch ex As SqlException
        ShowAlertMessage(ex.Message)
        GetDBField = Nothing
        Exit Function

    End Try

    'Cerrando la conexion de BD
    SqlDisconnect()

    GetDBField = result
End Function
```

Really in need of any kind of help

In replay to the last question all this code is in vb page in App_Code

```
#Region "   Variables Globales"
    Public db As String = "repuestosdr"

    'Public CnStr As String = "Driver={SQL Server Native Client 10.0};Server=localhost;Database=" & db & ";Uid=crivera;Pwd=crivera;"
    Public CnStr As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("SuoodConnection").ConnectionString    '"Driver={SQL Server};Server=repuestosdr.db.10580944.hostedresource.com;Database=" & db & ";Uid=" & db & ";Pwd=r34llyH4rd!;Port=1433;"

    Public Logged As Boolean = False

    Public Qry As String
    Public msg As New MsgBoxResult


    Public ds As New DataSet
    Public dt As New DataTable
    Public dr As SqlDataReader
    Public cn As New SqlConnection()
    Public da As New SqlDataAdapter
    Public cmd As SqlCommand


#End Region
```

for connection:

```
#Region "   Connection"
    Public Function SqlConnect(Optional ByVal MyPage As Page = Nothing) As Boolean
        Try
            If cn.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
                With cn
                    .ConnectionString = CnStr
                    .Open()
                End With
            End If

        Catch myerror As Exception
            ShowAlertMessage("Error Connecting to the Database" & Chr(13) & myerror.Message)
            SqlConnect = False
        End Try
        SqlConnect = True
    End Function
```

Comment: What is cn? Where do you define and initialize it?. Keeping global connection objects is a recipe for any kind of errors.

Comment: Hello Steve, I just edited my post

Comment: what happens if you invert the logic of the if statement in SqlConnect ... like this ... If cn.State <> ConnectionState.Open Then

Comment: PrfctByDsgn, I just changed it and the error still shows up

Comment: When you call ExecuteReader without any CommandBehavior options, it defaults to leaving the connection open until the Reader is closed. I do not see where you close the Reader. Also, can you post the code for SqlDisconnect().